# windowLightStatusBar doesn't work on Android 12 with splash transition disabled

Tags: android, androidx, android-12

I want the background of the system bars to match the theme background in both light and dark mode. As such, I have the following in my values-v27/styles.xml:

```xml
<style name="Theme.SystemBarColors" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
  <item name="android:statusBarColor">?android:attr/colorBackground</item>
  <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">?attr/isLightTheme</item>
  <item name="android:navigationBarColor">?android:attr/colorBackground</item>
  <item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">?attr/isLightTheme</item>
  <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
  <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
</style>
```

My app theme then has that as a parent. This seems to work fine on all relevant Android versions by itself.

However, I also want to disable the exit animation on the OS-provided splash screen. (The OS-provided splash hides to reveal an identical-looking splash screen that our app displays on all Android versions while Chrome is launching to show our TWA, so the exit animation makes the hand off look odd and less seamless.) To disable the exit animation, I call this in onCreate on Android 12+:

```java
getSplashScreen().setOnExitAnimationListener(SplashScreenView::remove);
```

This works to disable the animation, but has the unfortunate side effect on Android 12 and 12L of also causing `windowLightStatusBar` and `windowLightNavigationBar` no longer to take effect. `statusBarColor` and `navigationBarColor` are still applied, however, leading to an unfortunate white-on-almost-white appearance for the bars. This only happens in situations where the OS-provided splash is actually displayed. E.g., launch from Android Studio → no OS-splash → `windowLight*Bar` applied versus launch from home screen → OS-splash displayed → `windowLight*Bar` not applied.

In contrast `windowLight*Bar` *does* appear to be applied in both cases on Android 13, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if this is just an Android bug that was later fixed. However, even in the latter case, I'd appreciate any help finding a workaround that allows `windowLight*Bar` to be applied on 12 and 12L while still allowing a seamless handoff between the two identical-looking splash views.